# Adding new values to a text file

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, read-write

So basically I am creating an android app and one of the features is to simulate vitals. There are 4 variables: Temperature, Diastolic blood pressure, systolic blood pressure and heart rate. These 4 variables are randomly generated and are compared against set values and determines if the user is at risk. All this takes place in the CalculationRisk class.

The results are displayed in a text view like this:

```
Simulation Results
Temperature: 39
Diastolic Blood Pressure: 107
Systolic Blood Pressure: 224
Heart Rate: 151

Risk Results
Temperature: HIGH RISK
Diastolic Blood Pressure: NORMAL
Systolic Blood Pressure: HIGH RISK
Heart Rate: LOW RISK
```

Each measurement is stored in a table called MEASUREMENTS_TABLE in the class VitalsDB. What I want to do is by the click of a button I want these values to save to the text file called "text".

Text File:

```
    Height:   175
    Weight:   80

    Diastolic Blood Pressure:   100
    Systolic Blood Pressure:   100
    Heart Rate:   170
    Body Temperature:   100
```

This text file is stored in the assets folder and is read in the class SummaryCareRecord. But the thing is I want to add to the text file, so whatever is already there should be displayed with the values in the text view.

CalculationRisk:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

import static java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance;

public class CalculateRisk extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv_text2;
    String name = "";
    String address = "";
    String date_of_birth = "";
    String medication1 = "";
    String medication2 = "";
    String medication3 = "";
    String allergies = "";
    String bad_reactions = "";

    int height = 0;
    int weight = 0;

    int DBP = 0;
    int SBP = 0;
    int pulse_rate = 0;
    int blood_glucose = 0;
    int respiration_rate = 0;
    int body_temperature = 0;

    Button btn_pm;

    VitalsDB db;
    int highRiskCount = 0;

    String verdictTemp = null;
    String verdictHR = null;
    String verdictDBP = null;
    String verdictSBP = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate_risk);

        db = new VitalsDB(getBaseContext());

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CalculateRisk.this);
        int h = 0;
        int userPosition = preferences.getInt("positionCount", h);


        tv_text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv_text2.setText("");
        tv_text2.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        btn_pm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pm);

        btn_pm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(CalculateRisk.this, PastMeasurements.class));
            }
        });

        final TextView HRMeasureText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_label);

        ImageButton results = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_calculate);
        results.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           Random random = new Random();

                                           int SBP = random.nextInt(180) + 70;
                                           int DBP = random.nextInt(110) + 70;
                                           int pulse_rate = random.nextInt(180)+ 60;
                                           int body_temperature = random.nextInt(32)+ 10;


                        if (body_temperature > 38) {
                            verdictTemp = "HIGH RISK";
                            highRiskCount += 1;
                        } else if (body_temperature <= 38 && body_temperature > 37) {
                            verdictTemp = "LOW RISK";
                        } else if (body_temperature <= 37) {
                            verdictTemp = "NORMAL";
                        }

                        if (DBP >= 180) {
                            verdictDBP = "HIGH RISK";
                            highRiskCount += 1;
                        } else if (DBP < 180 && DBP > 120) {
                            verdictDBP = "LOW RISK";
                        } else if (DBP <= 120) {
                            verdictDBP = "NORMAL";
                        }

                        if (SBP >= 110) {
                            verdictSBP = "HIGH RISK";
                            highRiskCount += 1;
                        } else if (SBP < 110 && SBP > 80) {
                            verdictSBP = "LOW RISK";
                        } else if (SBP <= 80) {
                            verdictSBP = "NORMAL";
                        }

                        if (pulse_rate > 160) {
                            verdictHR = "HIGH RISK";
                            highRiskCount += 1;
                        } else if (pulse_rate <= 160 && pulse_rate > 72) {
                            verdictHR = "LOW RISK";
                        } else if (pulse_rate <= 72) {
                            verdictHR = "NORMAL";
                        }


                    HRMeasureText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output_riskyness);
                    output.setText(String.valueOf(highRiskCount));

                    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CalculateRisk.this);

                    int h = 0;
                    int userPosition = preferences.getInt("positionCount", h);

                    /***************************** INSERT NEW CALCULATION RECORD *********************/
                    Calculation calc = new Calculation();


                    //temperature data
                    calc.setTemperatureReading(body_temperature);
                    calc.setVerdictTemp(verdictTemp);

                    //Heart Rate data
                    calc.setHeartRateReading(pulse_rate);
                    calc.setVerdictHR(verdictHR);

                    //diastolic blood pressure data
                     calc.setDBPReading(DBP);
                     calc.setVerdictDBP(verdictDBP);

                    //diastolic blood pressure data
                    calc.setSBPReading(SBP);
                    calc.setVerdictSBP(verdictSBP);

                    //Date Data
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    String strDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

                    calc.setDate(strDate);

                    //Time Data
                    long millis = new Date().getTime();
                    String time = getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.UK).format(millis);

                    String strTime = time + " GMT";
                    calc.setTime(strTime);

                    db.open();
                    db.insertCalculation(calc);
                    db.close();

//                    final AlertDialog.Builder highRiskAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalculateRisk.this);
//                    highRiskAlert.setMessage("An SMS has been sent to alert your GP of your measurements, and an appointment will be booked. \n" +
//                            "\nPlease keep an eye on your inbox for your GP's confirmation of the appointment.");
//                    highRiskAlert.setTitle("HIGH RISK!");
//
//                    highRiskAlert.setCancelable(false);


                    AlertDialog.Builder resultAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalculateRisk.this);



                                           tv_text2.setText("\nSimulation Results: " + "\n\n" +
                            "Temperature: " + body_temperature +  "       Diastolic Blood Pressure: " + DBP + "\n\n" +

                            "Systolic Blood Pressure: " + SBP  + "        Heart Rate: " +  pulse_rate + "\n\n" + "\n\n"+

                                                   "Risk Results:" + "\n\n"+
                                                   "Temperature:" + verdictTemp + "        DBP:" + verdictDBP + "\n\n"+
                                           "SBP:" + verdictSBP + "              Heart Rate:" + verdictHR);

//                    resultAlert.setMessage("Results:" + "\n\n" +
//                            "Temperature Risk: " + verdictTemp + "\n\n" +
//                            "DBP Risk:" + verdictDBP + "\n\n" +
//                            "SBP Risk:" + verdictSBP + "\n\n" +
//                            "Heart Rate Risk:" + verdictHR
//                    );

                    if (verdictTemp == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Temperature too high");
                    }
                    if(verdictDBP == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING DBP too high");
                    }
                    if(verdictSBP == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING SBP too high");
                    }
                    if(verdictHR == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Heart Rate too high");
                    }


                    if(verdictTemp == "HIGH RISK" & verdictDBP == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Temperature and DBP too high ");
                    }
                    if(verdictTemp == "HIGH RISK" & verdictSBP == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Temperature and SBP too high");
                    }
                    if(verdictTemp == "HIGH RISK" & verdictHR == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Temperature and Heart Rate too high");
                    }

                    if(verdictDBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictSBP == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING DBP and SBP too high");
                    }
                    if(verdictDBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictHR == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING DBP and Heart Rate too high");
                    }

                    if(verdictSBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictHR == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING SBP and Heart Rate too high");
                    }


                    if(verdictTemp == "HIGH RISK" & verdictDBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictSBP == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Temperature, DBP and SBP too high PLEASE SEEK ATTENTION");
                    }
                    if(verdictTemp == "HIGH RISK" & verdictDBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictHR == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Temperature, DBP and Heart Rate too high PLEASE SEEK ATTENTION");
                    }
                    if(verdictTemp == "HIGH RISK" & verdictSBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictHR == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Temperature,SBP and Heart Rate too high PLEASE SEEK ATTENTION");
                    }

                    if(verdictDBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictSBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictHR == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING DBP, SBP and Heart Rate too high PLEASE SEEK ATTENTION");
                    }


                    if(verdictTemp == "HIGH RISK" & verdictDBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictSBP == "HIGH RISK" & verdictHR == "HIGH RISK"){
                        resultAlert.setMessage("WARNING Temperature,DBP, SBP and Heart Rate too high" + "\n\n" +
                        "PLEASE SEEK IMMEDIATE ATTENTION");
                    }





                    resultAlert.setTitle("Results");
                    resultAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            highRiskCount = 0;

                        }
                    });
                    resultAlert.setCancelable(false);
                    resultAlert.create().show();

                }

        });
        tv_text2.setText("Results");
    }
}
```

VitalsDB:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class VitalsDB {

    //variables for all columns in database
    private static final String TAG = "DBHelper";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "VitalsDB2";



    private static final String MEASUREMENTS_TABLE = "measurements";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEASUREMENTID = "measureid";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";
    public static final String COLUMN_TEMPERATURE = "temperature";
    public static final String COLUMN_TEMPERATURE_VERDICT = "temperature_verdict";
    public static final String COLUMN_SBP = "sbp";
    public static final String COLUMN_SBP_VERDICT = "sbp_verdict";
    public static final String COLUMN_DBP = "dbp";
    public static final String COLUMN_DBP_VERDICT = "dbp_verdict";
    public static final String COLUMN_HEARTRATE = "heartrate";
    public static final String COLUMN_HEARTRATE_VERDICT = "heartrate_verdict";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


//    public VitalsDB(Context context) {
//        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
//    }
//
//
//    //creating tables
//    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
//        String CREATE_MEASUREMENTS_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE" + MEASUREMENT_TABLE1 + "( MEASUREMENTID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Date TEXT, Time TEXT, Temperature INTEGER, Temperature_Verdict TEXT, Lbp INTEGER, Lbp_Verdict TEXT, Hbp INTEGER, Hbp_Verdict TEXT, Heartrate INTEGER, Heartrate_verdict TEXT) ";
//        db.execSQL(CREATE_MEASUREMENTS_TABLE1);
//        Log.d("DatabaseHandler","Database Created");
//    }
//
//
//    // Upgrading database
//    @Override
//    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
//        // Drop older table if existed
//        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MEASUREMENTS_TABLE1);
//        // Create tables again
//        onCreate(db);
//    }







    //string query to hold database table name and order of columns
    private static final String CREATE_MEASUREMENTS_TABLE = "create table "+ MEASUREMENTS_TABLE + "("
            + COLUMN_MEASUREMENTID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_DATE + " text, "
            + COLUMN_TIME + " text, "
            + COLUMN_TEMPERATURE + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_TEMPERATURE_VERDICT + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_SBP + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_SBP_VERDICT + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_DBP + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_DBP_VERDICT + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_HEARTRATE + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_HEARTRATE_VERDICT + " text not null )";




    //variables for holding database context, helper and SQLite instances
    private final Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    //method to create instance of database helper
    public VitalsDB(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        //generate instance of database helper with defined database name and version
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        //first method ran on load of class
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

            db.execSQL(CREATE_MEASUREMENTS_TABLE);
        }

        //if the database is updated, wipe it to prevent conflicts
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MEASUREMENTS_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //open database
    public VitalsDB open() throws SQLException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //sqlDB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //close the database
    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //add new row and calc to database
    public void insertCalculation(Calculation calc) {

        //populate rows with measurements
        ContentValues newCalc = new ContentValues();

        newCalc.put(COLUMN_TEMPERATURE, calc.getTemperatureReading());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_SBP, calc.getSBPReading());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_DBP, calc.getDBPReading());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_HEARTRATE, calc.getHeartRateReading());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_DATE, calc.getDate());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_TIME, calc.getTime());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_TEMPERATURE_VERDICT, calc.getVerdictTemp());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_SBP_VERDICT, calc.getVerdictSBP());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_DBP_VERDICT, calc.getVerdictDBP());
        newCalc.put(COLUMN_HEARTRATE_VERDICT, calc.getVerdictHR());

        db.insert(MEASUREMENTS_TABLE, null, newCalc);
    }

    public Cursor getCalculation() {
        //query database for current row for data


        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + MEASUREMENTS_TABLE, null);

        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        //return the cursor
        return mCursor;
    }
}
```

Summary Care Record:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class SummaryCareRecord extends Activity {

    Button b_read;
    TextView tv_text;
    String name = "";
    String address = "";
    String date_of_birth = "";
    String medication1 = "";
    String medication2 = "";
    String medication3 = "";
    String allergies = "";
    String bad_reactions = "";

    int height = 0;
    int weight = 0;

    int blood_pressure = 0;
    int pulse_rate = 0;
    int blood_glucose = 0;
    int respiration_rate = 0;
    int body_temperature = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scr);

        tv_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
     Read(tv_text);
    }


        public void Read(View view) {
            String text = "";
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("test.txt")));
                String line;
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                    text = text.concat(line + "\n");
//                    String[] lineVals = line.split(":");
//                    if(lineVals[0].equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
//                        name = lineVals[1].trim();
//                    } else if(lineVals[0].equalsIgnoreCase("height")){
//                        height = Integer.parseInt(lineVals[1].trim());
//                    }
//                    else if(lineVals[0].equalsIgnoreCase("weight")){
//                        weight = Integer.parseInt(lineVals[1].trim());
//                    }
//                    else if(lineVals[0].equalsIgnoreCase("blood pressure")){
//                        blood_pressure = Integer.parseInt(lineVals[1].trim());
//                    } else if(lineVals[0].equalsIgnoreCase("pulse rate")){
//                        pulse_rate = Integer.parseInt(lineVals[1].trim());
//                    }
//                    else if(lineVals[0].equalsIgnoreCase("blood glucose")){
//                        blood_glucose = Integer.parseInt(lineVals[1].trim());
//                    }
//                    else if(lineVals[0].equalsIgnoreCase("respiration rate")){
//                        respiration_rate = Integer.parseInt(lineVals[1].trim());
//                    }
//                    else if(lineVals[0].equalsIgnoreCase("body temperature")){
//                        body_temperature = Integer.parseInt(lineVals[1].trim());
//                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            tv_text.setText(text);

        }
    }
```

Pastmeasurements

Comment: Unclear: Text file OR database? If you already use a database, what's the use of duplicating the data on a text file?

Comment: I want to add the current measurement  which can be accessed from the database to the text file. It doesnt involve duplicating the data just adding new data to it.

Comment: It's simply **redundant**, to have the data **both** in the database **and** in a text file. I don't see the point in having **duplicate** data (so, "same data which is in 2 different places").

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the assets folder is protected and can only be read as it is part of the package used for installing the App and thus that you will be unable to save the file (any file) in the assets folder from within the App.

Of course you already have an extremely efficient and simple to use means of writing the data to a file and thus preserving the data and that is by using the SQLite database.

By the look of it you would be best served by adding a new table to your database with columns along the lines of name, height, weight, bp, bgl, rr and bt.